# Can't access default gateway hours after factory resetting router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, ipv4, gateway

I've gone through this cycle of events twice. Can't access default gateway `192.168.1.1`, so I factory reset the router, which fixes the issue, until it mysteriously stops working again a few hours later with this error message in browser:

> 192.168.1.1 took too long to respond.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

All the while I'm able to successfully use the internet through this same router.

I'm accessing it off the same computer the whole time (both when it works immediately after factory reset, as well as when it stops working). Computer is connected to router directly via ethernet. It fails on both Edge and Chrome. I've tried http://192.168.1.1 and https://192.168.1.1. I've tried resetting the router normally (not factory reset, just power off on). I've tried restarting my desktop computer. None of this has worked. Only a factory reset of the router works -- temporarily -- but I wish to avoid this since I don't want the parental controls to be erased since it takes a while to enter. I assume the issue is to do with ipv6?

If I ping the default gateway, it works fine:

[image]

Tracert:

[image]

I'm using the correct default gateway, I think:

[image]

EDIT: This is `arp -a` when it's broken:

[image]

This is `arp -a` when it's working (1 minute after factory reset):

[image]

After the recent factory reset, it's back to working:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't sound like it has anything to do with IPv6. (You're connecting to an IPv4 address...) What does `arp -a` say about the router's MAC address? Both when it works and when it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1686 Added this to my Q.

Comment: Ok, so that rules out things like duplicate IP addresses... Does this keep happening _after_ you've re-entered all the parental control rules after the factory reset, or does it still happen without?

Comment: @user1686 I haven't run that experiment, but I will say that if a site is blocked due to parental controls, the error message is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, but when it comes to my default gateway the error is `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`